# in app purchase saving buttons states

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am trying to develop an app with in app purchases in it, simply what I want to do is to have two buttons one to make the purchase(enabled) the second button to open the activity after purchase (at first is disabled then after purchase is enabled).
Two problems the first was to save the buttons state after the purchase as they were getting reset every time I restart the app. So I did some researches and found about shared preference and I did implemented it but the second problem came out that buttons statuses doesn’t seem to work right (between disabled to enabled) after implementing shared preference.

Note that in the app I have two buttons that do the same thing one enables the other buttons but with no purchase made and they work fine with shared preference, but the buttons associated with the in app purchase stopped changing their status from disabled to enabled after the purchase is made (they stay disabled after the purchase)

Here is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainScreen">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Activity 1"
    android:id="@+id/act1"
    android:onClick="Activity1"
    android:layout_marginTop="84dp"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buyall"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buyall"
    android:enabled="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Buy Act 1"
    android:id="@+id/buyButton"
    android:onClick="buyClick"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/act1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/act1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/act1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
    android:enabled="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Activity 2"
    android:id="@+id/act2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/act1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/act1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/act1"
    android:onClick="Activity2"

    android:enabled="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Buy act 2"
    android:id="@+id/buyact2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/act2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buyButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buyButton"
    android:onClick="buyAct2"
    android:enabled="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Activity 3"
    android:id="@+id/act3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/act2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/act2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/act2"
    android:onClick="Activity3"

    android:enabled="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Buy act 3"
    android:id="@+id/buyact3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/act3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buyact2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buyact2"
    android:onClick="buyAct3"
    android:enabled="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Buy all"
    android:id="@+id/buyall"
    android:onClick="buyAll"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eact4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ACT 4"
    android:id="@+id/act4"

    android:onClick="ACT4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/act3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/act3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/act3"
    android:enabled="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enable ACT 4"
    android:id="@+id/eact4"
    android:onClick="EACT4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buyact3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buyact3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buyact3"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

And that’s my java code:

```
    package com.aseng90_test.smiap2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.aseng90_test.smiap2.util.IabHelper;
import com.aseng90_test.smiap2.util.IabResult;
import com.aseng90_test.smiap2.util.Purchase;


public class MainScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final String TAG = "com.aseng90_test.smiap2";
IabHelper mHelper;
private static final String ITEM_SKU = "com.aseng90_test.smiap2_button555";
private static final String ITEM_SKU2 = "com.aseng90_test.smiap2_buyact222";
private static final String ITEM_SKU3 = "com.aseng90_test.smiap2_buyact333";
private static final String ITEM_SKU4 = "com.aseng90_test.smiap2_buyall_11";








private Button Activity1;
private Button Activity2;
private Button Activity3;

private Button buyButton;
private Button buyAct2;
private Button buyAct3;
private Button buyAll;

private Button EAct4;
private Button Act4;


private SharedPreferences prefs;
private String prefName = "MyPref";


boolean Activity1_isEnabled;
boolean Activity2_isEnabled;
boolean Activity3_isEnabled;
boolean Act4_isEnabled;


boolean buyButton_isEnabled;
boolean buyAct2_isEnabled;
boolean buyAct3_isEnabled;
boolean buyAll_isEnabled;
boolean EAct4_isEnabled;

private static final String Activity1_state = "Activity1_state";
private static final String Activity2_State = "Activity2_state";
private static final String Activity3_State = "Activity3_state";
private static final String buyButton_State = "buyButton_state";
private static final String buyAct2_State = "buyAct2_state";
private static final String buyAct3_State = "buyAct3_state";
private static final String buyAll_State = "buyAll_state";
private static final String Act4_State = "Act4_state";
private static final String EAct4_State = "EAct4_state";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

    buyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyButton);
    buyAct2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyact2);
    buyAct3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyact3);
    buyAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyall);


    Activity1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.act1);
    Activity2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.act2);
    Activity3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.act3);



    EAct4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eact4);
    Act4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.act4);


    String base64EncodedPublicKey =
            "";

    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new
                               IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                                   public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                                       if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                           Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + result);
                                       } else {
                                           Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                                       }
                                   }
                               });
}


public void EACT4(View view) {
    EAct4.setEnabled(false);
    Act4.setEnabled(true);
}

public void ACT4(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this,
            "ACt4 Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


public void buyClick(View view) {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
}

public void buyAct2(View view) {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU2, 10002, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "buyact2");
}

public void buyAct3(View view) {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU3, 10003, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "buyact3");
}

public void buyAll(View view) {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU4, 10004, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "buyall");
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}


IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                      Purchase purchase) {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle error
            return;
        }
        if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            Activity1.setEnabled(true);
            buyButton.setEnabled(false);

        }

        if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU2)) {
            Activity2.setEnabled(true);
            buyAct2.setEnabled(false);
        }

        if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU3)) {
            Activity3.setEnabled(true);
            buyAct3.setEnabled(false);
        }

        if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU4)) {
            Activity1.setEnabled(true);
            Activity2.setEnabled(true);
            Activity3.setEnabled(true);

            buyAll.setEnabled(false);
            buyButton.setEnabled(false);
            buyAct2.setEnabled(false);
            buyAct3.setEnabled(false);

        }


    }


};


public void Activity1(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(MainScreen.this, Click1.class));

}

public void Activity2(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(MainScreen.this, Activity2.class));
}

public void Activity3(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(MainScreen.this, Activity3.class));
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
    mHelper = null;
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    if (Act4.isEnabled()){
        Act4_isEnabled = true;
    }
    else {
        Act4_isEnabled = false;
    }


    if (Activity1.isEnabled()){
        Activity1_isEnabled = true;
    }
    else {
        Activity1_isEnabled = false;
    }

    if (Activity2.isEnabled()){
        Activity2_isEnabled = true;
    }
    else {
        Activity2_isEnabled = false;
    }

    if (Activity3.isEnabled()){
        Activity3_isEnabled = true;
    }
    else {
        Activity3_isEnabled = false;
    }

    if (buyButton.isEnabled()){
        buyButton_isEnabled = true;
    }
    else {
        buyButton_isEnabled = false;
    }

    if (buyAct2.isEnabled()){
        buyAct2_isEnabled = true;
    }
    else {
        buyAct2_isEnabled = false;
    }

    if (buyAct3.isEnabled()){
        buyAct3_isEnabled = true;
    }
    else {
        buyAct3_isEnabled = false;
    }

    if (buyAll.isEnabled()){
        buyAll_isEnabled = true;
    }
    else {
        buyAll_isEnabled = false;
    }



    prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName,MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putString(Activity1_state,this.getLocalClassName());

    editor.putBoolean(Act4_State,Act4_isEnabled);
    editor.putBoolean(EAct4_State,EAct4_isEnabled);
    editor.putBoolean(Activity1_state,Activity1_isEnabled);
    editor.putBoolean(Activity2_State,Activity2_isEnabled);
    editor.putBoolean(Activity3_State,Activity3_isEnabled);
    editor.putBoolean(buyButton_State,buyButton_isEnabled);
    editor.putBoolean(buyAct2_State,buyAct2_isEnabled);
    editor.putBoolean(buyAct3_State,buyAct3_isEnabled);
    editor.putBoolean(buyAll_State,buyAll_isEnabled);
    editor.apply();

}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName,MODE_PRIVATE);




    Act4.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(Act4_State,false));
    Activity1.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(Activity1_state,false));
    Activity2.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(Activity2_State,false));
    Activity3.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(Activity3_State,false));

    EAct4.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(EAct4_State,true));
    buyButton.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(buyButton_State,true));
    buyAct2.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(buyAct2_State,true));
    buyAct3.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(buyAct3_State,true));
    buyAll.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(buyAll_State,true));
}
```

So Any suggestions if I have something wrong in my code?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call methods from Java part , don't call from xml using android:onClick

Use default value of the button(buy) state to false in shared preference .

and in this screen implement this **if** check inside oncreate() method as:

```
if(button(buy) state ==false)
{
 //make button(buy) state enable
 //make activity button state disable
}
else
{
//make button(buy) state disable
//make activity button state enable
}
```

And make button(buy) and activity calling button state to true/false according to result after in app purchase and also update shared prefrence state according to result